# Kohana and ExtJS or JQuery for Intranet

Tags: jquery, kohana, extjs4

In the process of building an intranet. We have lots of tables and data to show/edit/review and I want the most functional solution.

I like the extjs widgets and since I am only creating an in-house solution, I believe the licensing allows me to use it without paying.

Anyone with some opinion on the best way forward on this? I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ext JS is tripple licensed under

- [Sencha Commercial License](http://www.sencha.com/legal/sencha-commercial-software-license-agreement/) for applications whose source code you want to keep proprietary.
- Sencha Commercial OEM License if you want to use Ext JS to create your own commercially licensed SDK.
- [GNU GPL license v3](http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html) for developing open source software.

You have to buy the first two license types, only the GPL 3 licensed framework is for free.

It doesn't depend if you build a public application or an in-house application, it depends whether you make your application open source or not.

So when you don't want to pay, it's not legal to use it in an in-house application.

You can read more at the [Ext JS licensing page](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/license/).

Comment: Good answer, +1... mind if I summarize...?      He has 3 options:  1)pay  2)open source the in-house solution  3)go with jQuery

Answer (score 6):

Netzpirat's answer is misleading.
  The GNU GPL v3 license requires you to distribute the source code with any release of the software. Web based applications aren't distributed in the traditional way that GPL assumes, so FSF modified the license to include "conveyance", which is debatable whether it ever really applies.
  If conveyance does not apply, you're home free.
  In the event that conveyance would apply, the software is restricted in this case to inhouse employees and from a licensing point of view, they would be acting for the company and not be entitled to the source code.
  The GPL is specifically designed to allow for inhouse usage of GPL'd software -- e. g. the GCC suite, without requiring distribution of modifications so long as the modified software is not distributed, but kept inhouse.

In summary, you're quite right in assuming you'll be able to use the library under the GPL v3 license.

Comment: I agree with your assessment of "in-house", however javascript and conveyance is a tricky issue.  Whereas your GPLed server-side code responding to http requests is certainly not conveyance under the GPL, your javascript is first delivered to the user, then *executed in their browser*.  This distinction is crucial, and is somewhat debated.  Unfortunately it has yet to be tried in a legal sense.  Here is one good article on the subject:
http://steveluscher.com/archives/the-free-software-movement-and-the-gnu-gpl-in-the-age-of-javascript

Answer (score 2):

Sencha, Inc. (Ext.js) now provides its definition of "conveyance", which is really the part of the GPL that concerns the delivery of Javascript to a user to be exectued, on its FAQ page under the heading "What is Sencha’s interpretation of “conveyance” under the GPL v3?"  In part, Sencha asserts:

> Since Ext JS, Sencha GXT and Sencha Touch are software programs that can run within the browser while disconnected from the network or the rest of a server program; when a Sencha based interface is embedded in a web-page served to a user who *does not have an employee relationship with the original licensed entity*, we consider that “conveyance” rather than simple web page “propagation” as defined by the GPL v3 has occurred, and the source code of the whole application must be provided to the user.

http://www.sencha.com/legal/open-source-faq/

Because your users would all have "an employee relationship with the original licensed entity," Sencha seems to agree with zrvan that it is acceptable not to license the entire the project under the GPL.  Furthermore, this is only Sencha's interpretation of conveyance, which may not reflect how a court would interpret it.  At least you can feel somewhat comfortable knowing that you're in compliance with the author's definition.